# Dots pen-and-paper game in Python

Tags: python

I am looking for an implementation of this game in Python:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_(game)

Can anyone point me to one? Or to a similar game implementation?

Answer (score 1):

Something like [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/38732/multiplayer-game-programming-for-teens-with-python) or [this](http://pythonpalace.blogspot.ch/2015/03/dotsnboxes.html)? Also, Pygame has some nice [examples](http://www.pygame.org/tags/example) and should be a good place to start when you plan to create your own game.

Comment: This is a different game, but thanks for the links.